# PHP: Save data from hosted site to localhost

Tags: php

I am running on a hosted site where all my files and databases are stored in my hosting service.

Problem is, whenever a user saves data, it stores that data in my online database. Is there a way for me to save a copy of that data on my local server in order for my local server to access the new data for other purposes like sending sms?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the server? Who is the hosting company? Do they have ftp/ssh/etc. access?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MySql? If so, you may take a look at MySql Replication:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your hosted database (you have FTP to your service, and check out the db configuration), you could create a PHP, which connects to your hosted database, retrieves your data, then connects to your local database (if it has public IP/hostname, and the database port is open (firewall?), and put all your data there.

Comment: Yes. I can access my hosted database. What should I do first?

Comment: First you should export your schema (the tables from your db), then you should import it to your local copy. Then write your PHP code, and that's it. :)

Comment: yes yes. the import and export. are you saying that i have to import and export all the time?

Comment: Nah - just for the first time, in order to get the schema. After that the differences should be handled by your php code, but to get that working, you will need the same schema on your side too. Thats why the export/import phase is important.

Comment: how do i do the php side?

Comment: You must write PHP code. Or - as mentioned before, its easier to connect to the remote repo. Btw. cant you just send your text messages to the users by looking up the data in your hosted database? Seems less painful.

Comment: my country does not support the number@company.com.

Comment: i only know how to save the data in the hosted database. i have no idea how to do it for the local part

Comment: Do you have a PHP/sql developer nearby? My recommendation is in this case to find someone to do it for you. Without the proper knowledge, it would take you far too much time and effort, I think. On the other hand you can start learning always. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just use remote MySQL connection. You should be able to connect to your server database directly from your local environment by simply providing the hosted DB IP address in your PDO Connection settings.

```
<?php
$serverIp='123.123.123.123'
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host='.$serverIp;
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: where can I get my serverIp and dsn?

Comment: will this work if i post one copy on my hosted database and one on the database on my local server?

Comment: You will need to speak to your hosting company to get the server IP etc.

Comment: By working this way you don't need a local database on your local server, you are using the main database. In the long run this is a much better idea in keeping with the KISS philosophy.

Comment: is the serverip different from the ip? or are they the same?

Comment: my problem without using a local database in my local folder is i cannot run my vb.net application for sending out sms on my local server

Comment: I'm sure VB.net will have a way of connecting to a remote server as well though I can't advise, might be another question you need to ask